# Сохранение настроек пользователя между сеансами

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, я никак не могу нормально разобраться с настройками. Вот у меня есть цвет формы (красный), я в настройках прописал его красным. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, появлялось диалоговое окно выбора цвета, и цвет формы становился цветом, который выбрал пользователь? Но как это сделать я знаю, но вот как это сделать так, чтобы при последующем запуске программы этот цвет сохранился?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы цвет сохранился - его надо сохранить. Для этого предназначены Application Settings и User Settings.
Про работу с ними можно почитать в MSDN. Начните, например, [отсюда](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397759.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую забайндить цвет формы на поле настроек. Дальше всё произойдёт автоматически (свойство Bindings в дизайнере, добавляете туда свойство, выбираете источник данных - настройки).

Если что-то не сохраняется при перезагрузке, скорее всего, дело в том, что файл настроек пересоздаётся при компиляции.